Pass value of <option> to onChange function in React using Props
I am trying to call a function from onChange event of <select> tag.
<select id="select-option" onChange = {() => this.props.onPressed(this.value)}>
     <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
     <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
     <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
     <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>

I want to pass the value of the <option> to onPressed() function. How can I do it?

Can you please code sand link

what currently happens with your code?

@JaromandaX If I log the value of the argument that I am passing to onPressed() function. It is coming as undefined.

that means this is NOT the select element - clearly not since it has this.props.onPressed ... perhaps (e) => this.props.onPressed(e.target.value)

Get the value from the event's target instead.
onChange={e => this.props.onPressed(e.target.value)}

